# An infinite dimensional normed linear space is the union of two disjoint convex sets

Tags: general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional normed linear space. I want to show that there exist two disjoint convex sets $C_1$ and $C_2$ such that $X=C_1\cup C_2$ and both $C_1$ and $C_2$ are dense in $X$.

I proceed as follows: Since $X$ is infinite dimensional, there exists a discontinuous linear functional $f:X\to \mathbb K$. Then ker$f$ is dense in $X$. If we consider $C_1=\{x\in X:f(x)<0\}$ and $C_2=\{x\in X:f(x)\geq 0\}$, then $X=C_1\cup C_2$ and $C_1\cap C_2=\emptyset$. Since $C_2$ contains ker$f$, therefore, $C_2$ is dense. Also $C_1$ and $C_2$ are convex sets. But how to show that $C_1$ is dense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f$ is not the trivial functional it is surjective. In particular, there exists $v$ such that $f(v)=-1$. Now $C_1$ contains the $v$-translation of $\ker f$: 
$$
v+\ker f\subset C_1,$$
and the left hand side is dense as it is the translation of a dense set.

Answer (score 4):

Consider a sequence $(y_n)$ of elements of $X$ with unit norm and such that $f(y_n)\leqslant -n^2$ (such a sequence exists since $f$ is not continuous; indeed, since $\sup_{\lVert x\rVert =1}f(x)$ is infinite, we can find a sequence $(z_n)$ of unit vectors such that $|f(z_n)|\geqslant n^2$ for each $n$ and choose $y_n$ equal to $-z_n$ if $f(z_n)\geqslant n^2$ or $z_n$ if $-f(z_n)\geqslant n^2$). If $x$ is an element of $X$, define $x_n:=x+n^{-1}y_n$; then $\lVert x-x_n\rVert\to 0$ and 
$$f(x_n)=f(x) +\frac 1nf(y_n) \leqslant f(x)-n,$$
hence $x_n$ belongs to $C_1$ for $n$ large enough.

Comment: How to prove such function exists when f is not continuous? Could you please elaborate little bit..

Comment: @Lusin Which "function" you mean? Don't you mean instead the sequence $(y_n)$?

Comment: i mean how we know for  $(y_n)$  with unit norm, $f(y_n)\leq -n^2$ exists

Comment: @Lusin I have edited in order to include details.